# Where is \noident defined?

Tags: macros, packages

As always, I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}        %∑
\usepackage{hyperref}   %clickable x-ref-s
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}

%%% Set the fonts
\usepackage{mathpazo}       %use hott font

\begin{document}

ttadddddddd ttadddddddd **strong text** ttadddddddd ttadddddddd
\noident ttadddddddd ttadddddddd **strong text** ttadddddddd

\end{document}
```

which does not compile (seemingly due to the lack of a definition for `\noident`). Where is it defined?

Comment: `\noindent`. Also it's recommended to use `utf8` option rather than `utf8x`.

Comment: Nowhere. You probably want `\noindent`

Comment: oh gawd. i must rest

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a typo in the code.

Comment: @Manuel: `$∑$` doesn't compile w/out the `x`

Comment: @jaam You can do it with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2211}{\sum}`, and, if you are lazy or not organized, or just prefer to input it directly, you have `\usepackage{newunicodechar} \newunicodechar{∑}{\sum}`. With the `x` you get more defined by default, but it breaks other things. Without the `x` you just have to define them yourself (you can write all at once, and then load the file in any document you want to compile).

Comment: @Manuel: `$\sum$` works w/out me having to declare or use anything. `\usepackage{newunicodechar} \newunicodechar{∑}{\sum} $∑$` doesn't work. Neither does `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2211}{\sum}` (even w/ `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{amssymb}`). In sum: it's easiest to use just `$\sum$` (or even `\newcommand{\s}{\sum}`). (There's also `$\Sigma$` but it's lower)

Comment: @jaam It does work: `\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2211}{\sum}
\begin{document} $∑$ \end{document}`

Comment: @Manuel: True, now it works. I must have messed something up